# Visual Studio HTML tag navigation with keyboard

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there an easier way to keyboard navigate around tags in Visual Studio?

I find it very frustrating navigating around tags. Often I use <kbd>Ctrl + Left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd> to get through words quickly, but when editing HTML, a "word" often means characters like <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, etc, so to get from the right side of a `<div>` to the right side still takes 3 <kbd>Ctrl + Right</kbd>s. And if the div has other attributes, forget about it. Might as well pick up the mouse.

Does anyone know of a shortcut or a strategy to make it easier to navigate across a tag in html? Or an extension that lets you do this kind of navigation?